# How do I maximize a sum of exponentials?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Given:

$$f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{-b_i t}$$

for $a_i$ constant real numbers, and $b_i\ge 0$ unique and constant positive real numbers.  How do I find the supremum of $f$ on $[0, s]$, $s>0$?

I probably want to take the derivative and set it to zero and solve for $t$ there, (let's call it $t_0$), and then I know that the maximum is either $f(s)$, $f(0) = \sum_i a_i$ or $f(t_0)$.

The derivative is

$$f'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n -a_ib_ie^{-b_i t}.$$

However, I don't see how to solve for $t_0$ after setting this to zero. I recognize that there may be multiple roots, but intuitively there should not be more than $n$ such roots.

Currently, I am bounding $f$ on the interval by using $t=s$ when $a_i$ is negative and $t=0$ otherwise.  This bound is not tight enough for my purpose.

Comment: is numerical solution an option? it's an infinitely smooth function, you should converge very quickly

Comment: @gt6989b it's a good idea, but it's not simple since all of this needs to also work in tensorflow.  I'll check that out, or else I may look into using a different equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is going to be a hard problem.  You might try replacing $e^{-t}$ by $x$, changing your problem to maximizing

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^{b_i}$$

on the interval $[e^{-s},1]$.  If your $b_i$'s are not too ugly, this might be more tractible.

Comment: I think this is the right idea.  My particular set of $b_i$s ([  2.  20.  40.  21.]) don't seem to give a simple polynomial.